# SCSS change before element on parents hover

Tags: css, sass

I'd like to change my buttons `before` elements CSS when hovering over the `button` in SCSS. In this case, I want to change `width:0%` to `width:100%`. 
With my current code, it doesn't trigger at all. Here's a demo of how I wrote it along with some other CSS: [JSFIDDLE Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/skx0hLg3/)

Comment: Try this: `&:hover { &:before { width:100%; } }` or `&:hover:before`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&:hover:before`, [here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/skx0hLg3/1/)